# Using right angle clamps

Tags: clamps

I am having trouble using a corner clamp for my 45 degree miters. I try my best to align them and tighten them but the wood is always moving out of place.

What is the best method or just how they are used in general? I just can not figure out how to get a tight, corner joint.

Update v1.2: This is the type of clamp I have.
[image]

Update v1.3: I forgot to say, this image came from google. Do not know what site but image of the same thing (just different angle shot) from HomeDepot

Comment: Need to know which style of right-angle clamp you have. There are two or three main types and they work differently. Link to a picture, or better yet add the picture to the Question to help future searchers.

Comment: k i will add a pic off google. did not even realize there are different styles...

Comment: Thanks for adding the pic. That's the style I thought you meant, just didn't want to assume and post not-really-relevant info :-)

Comment: Ya, should have thought of adding the picture sooner :) . But some of these answers do give little good tips in my book.

Comment: Taping your miters is also a really effective way to hold alignment. For miterfolding parts, our shop will lay the parts flat, with the long point of each miter touch, then tape the joint, and then fold it together.

Comment: @Jacob Edmond I have used tape on some smaller projects. What tape do you use?

Comment: Box tape like 3M 355 or 3M 8992 Green Tape.

Answer (score 4):

I would invest in some of thise: [Collins Miter Clamps](https://www.collinstool.com/base.php?page=collins_miter_clamps.htm)

I bought a set a little over a year ago, and I'll never do miters without them. They are especially great for trim work.

[image: from Collins web page]

[image: from Collins web page]

Comment: They look very nice, what is the price on these?

Comment: Those look like they'd work well, even better than the old DIY version of the same thing clipped from bed springs. My only objection to these is the divots left behind, small though they are.

Comment: @Graphus I was thinking of that. Depending on the situation I was thinking of simply using a small block of wood. May have to give on side texture, like a wire brush. Otherwise I think these would work much better to what I am using. A set of 4 is about $20. Then $15 for another 4 clamps. Or 12 for like $30 or something. encase if anybody wanted to know.

Comment: @Ljk2000 Before you rush out to buy anything wait until you see my Answer. I'll try to post later on today.

Comment: There is another brand of similar style clamps, but these leave a much smaller indentation that them. For paint grade, it is so small, you won't even have to use any wood filler in most cases, and for stain grain, it will normally not be noticeable. I ran all not base, casing, crown, and wainscot through my house with these over the last year, and I only wish I had more.

Comment: @Graphus don't worry, I do not plan on buying any of either clamp. I have 4 of the clamps shown above. I mainly listed the price for people. And I looked it up just to see.

Comment: I hope @Graphus is ok...it's not like him to keep us in suspense! :)

Comment: @rob My pending reply was being held in the composition window but it went away :-( I thought it would be retained indefinitely. Now I know!

Comment: @Graphus oh no, I thought it usually saved it too. :(

Comment: @Graphus Jeez, man, this is even worse than when Firefly got cancelled, haha.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion although it looks simple this joint is as difficult as some of the more technically difficult ones. First off make sure all are cut true and to length, then my choice is band clamps with a dry run. Once everything is assured with the dry run then add glue :) mine still sometimes move when you add the glue. Don't forget the joint may need reinforcement with splines or something but i add these when dry.

Comment: I try to do this by using my hands and best I can line them up. When I got them lined up nice I use a square and check. My miter seems to fairly accurate but should use my chamfer bit on the router. Just planed them too thin, dumb mistake I made.